# Winforms DataGridView.Rows.Cells[] -> which is faster? Cells[int] or Cells[string]

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, datagridview

Hey Guys :)

```
  dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] 
                  VS 
  dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Zone"]
```

Can you please explain which is faster and why?

*And please explain how the string lookup works.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no indexer for string on `DataGridViewRowCollection`, that code doesn't compile against `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` see also https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewRowCollection.cs

Comment: sorry I did a mistake -> the Rows[0] is always int

Comment: i thought maybe there is some kind of Dictionary<string, T>  implantation

Comment: `System.Data.DataReader` has both `int` and `string` indexers, perhaps you meant something like that?

Comment: yes, but do the string index slower? and if Yes, how much slower. I have a table with 200 rows that updates(values in some cells) every 100 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

The only way the code above actually works if it is with a different type than `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` or there is an extension method on it somewhere perhaps.

Most implementations of any collection the `dataGridView1.Rows[0]` is going to be faster since what the `dataGridView1.Rows["PositionID"]` version does is go lookup the index and then do exactly what you did with the `dataGridView1.Rows[0]`